# Excel formula that if true uses value but if false repeats until true

Tags: excel

My formula is

```
=NORM.INV(RAND(), 0.08, 0.06)
```

basically generating random values in the normal distribution with probability between 0 and 1, mean 0.08 and standard deviation 0.06. What I need to happen is ensure that my output is greater than or equal to 0.03. Basically, if the output of the formula is greater than or equal to 0.03, fantastic, put that output in the cell. If the output of the formula is less than 0.03, repeat until greater and then use that value etc etc. Cannot seem to work it out

Comment: Without VBA, perhaps one way would be to filter the results to weed out the ones you don't want?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need there to be a value in each of the cells that the formula is working on and they are then multiplied by other cells

Comment: A screenshot might help. A formula cannot reference itself so you might need VBA.

Comment: formulas cannot help here, you need to define and use your own defined VBA function

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the formula work until the desired result is achieved, but you can limit the parameters so that the non-desired result will not achieved. In this case, the `RAND` should be limited to values greater than 0.2025. You can use `RANDBETWEEN`:

```
=NORM.INV(RANDBETWEEN(2025;10^4)/10^4; 0.08; 0.06)
```

[image]